# Converting textlinks to html hyperlinks

Tags: html, text

I'm trying to create a script where all files found in a search will be transformed to href-links and redirected to a html-file.

Say I'm searching for "word" and it gives the following hits:

```
/archive/here/is/the/first/found/file1.txt
/archive/here/is/the/second/found/file2.txt
/archive/here/is/the/third/found/file3.txt
```

I would like to redirect these hits and convert to a file "hits.html" containing:

```
<a href="/archive/here/is/the/first/found/file1.txt">file1.txt</a>
<a href="/archive/here/is/the/second/found/file2.txt">file2.txt</a>
<a href="/archive/here/is/the/third/found/file3.txt">file3.txt</a>
```

Could this be done (in a not too complicated way)?

I've tried latex2html but haven't been able to do it.

Comment: You're writing a script - in what language?

Comment: wrt to your "disappearing" hyperlinks - StackOverflow allows your questions to contain [some inline HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html). You should read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), or check out the [formatting reference provided when you are writing your question](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e29f4970b-pi)

Comment: #!/bin/bash

cat word.txt | ( while read line; do 
                        A=`echo $line`;
                        B=`echo $A | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'`;
                        echo "<a href="$A">$B</a>" >> hits.html; 
                done; )

exit 0